# Matplotlib/Pandas scatter plot fails on date 'deltas'

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to visuallize data relative to the difference in time since a certain event's date.

I am subtracting the event's date form a series of dates.

When trying to plot it using 'scatter' it fails with this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot cast scalar from dtype('<m8[ns]') to dtype('<m8') according to the rule 'same_kind'
```

'Plot' on the other hand works find.

How can I make this work with 'scatter'?

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd


dates = ["Tue  2 Jun 16:55:51 CEST 2015",
"Wed  3 Jun 14:51:49 CEST 2015",
"Fri  5 Jun 10:31:59 CEST 2015",
"Sat  6 Jun 20:47:31 CEST 2015",
"Sun  7 Jun 13:58:23 CEST 2015",
"Mon  8 Jun 14:56:49 CEST 2015",
"Tue  9 Jun 23:39:11 CEST 2015",
"Sat 13 Jun 16:55:26 CEST 2015",
"Sun 14 Jun 15:52:34 CEST 2015",
"Sun 15 Jun 16:17:24 CEST 2015",
"Mon 16 Jun 13:23:18 CEST 2015"]

delta_dates = pd.to_datetime(dates) - pd.to_datetime("Tue  9 Jun 23:39:11 CEST 2015")


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(delta_dates, [1]*len(delta_dates)) # WORKS
ax.scatter(delta_dates, [1]*len(delta_dates)) # FAILS
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the `TimedeltaIndex` to a `Float64Index` using `np.timedelta64`. For example, to plot the `delta_date` in seconds, use

```
delta_dates = (pd.to_datetime(dates) - pd.to_datetime("Tue  9 Jun 23:39:11 CEST 2015")) / np.timedelta64(1, "s")
```

This then works with `ax.scatter`.

Comment: BTW, what would be the best way to preserve the x-labels of the actual deltas?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "actual deltas". Do you mean `delta_dates` as you defined it in your question, as a `TimedeltaIndex`?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the most elegant solution, but I'd do `xticks = ax.get_xticks()`, convert that to a TimedeltaIndex with `date_labels = pd.TimedeltaIndex(xticks, "s")`, and then set those as the new tick labels with `ax.set_xticklabels(date_labels)`.